# how can i install nvm when I get the below error during installation

Tags: node.js, nvm

When i try to install nvm i receive error like this:

> nvm install 18.12.1
> -bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No such file or directory
> -bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No such file or directory
> Version '18.12.1' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.

after this bash, installation has stopped

Someone know what can I do to resolve this problem??
many thx for any answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To install node with nvm:

Clone nvm repo:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git ~/.nvm
```

Add the below line to the end of your script file `~/.bashrc` (if you use bash) or `~/.zshrc` (if you use zsh):

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Then run:

```bash
source ~/.zshrc
sudo snap remove curl # This is just to ensure cURL is updated 
sudo apt install curl
nvm install node
```